# How to split rows into distinct periods with NULL rows as the separator SQL (SSMS)

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to add a column equivalent to the "Period" column below and in the photo if you can view it. How would you go about adding a column that specifies which period a given date is in where the NULL values are the "partitions" so to speak?

| ValidDat | ID | Covereddt | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | xxx | 1/1/23 | 1 |
| 2/1/23 | xxx | 2/1/23 | 1 |
| 3/1/23 | xxx | NULL | NULL |
| 4/1/23 | xxx | 4/1/23 | 2 |
| 5/1/23 | xxx | 5/1/23 | 2 |
| 6/1/23 | xxx | NULL | NULL |
| 7/1/23 | xxx | 7/1/23 | 3 |

I've tried different variations of lead and lag functions, ctes, etc. and I just can't figure it out.

Edit to remove the photo, hopefully the actual table suffices
Edit to specify that these NULL periods could fall on different dates for different IDs, so they would not always be on 3/1, 6/1, etc.
Thanks!

Comment: "I've tried different variations of lead and lag functions".  Where???  We don't see a single query in this post.

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Sorry Eric, I've been writing and rewriting all day and didn't think to save each failed attempt at the time. This is also the first time I've asked anything on here, so I'm sorry I'm not a pro at the etiquette. But I believe you can simply move on from my question if you don't like how it was asked.

Comment: Thanks Stu, I'll keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: The last coveredDt (6/1/2023), should that be 7/1/2023? Do covered dates always line up with valid dates?

Comment: Yeah, it should. I'll edit that again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you define your periods but based on the 'photo', you need a case expression.

```
CASE WHEN Covereddt IS NULL THEN NULL 
     WHEN ValidDat BETWEEN '1/1/2023' AND  '2/28/2023' THEN 1
     WHEN ValidDat BETWEEN '3/1/2023' AND  '6/30/2023' THEN 2
     WHEN ValidDat BETWEEN '7/1/2023' AND '12/31/2023' THEN 3
 END AS Period
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to specify that the NULL periods would not be constant, so I couldn't just specify in a case statement. I appreciate the help though! I will edit my post to say that. :)